# Return parameters from c# to Python

Tags: c#, python

I am using PyCharm 2017.1.2 and Visual Studio 2015, I saw the post Jan 27 '14 at 10:58 David Heffernan but could not get it to work.  Parameters work correctly going from c# to Python but not the other way around.  Any thoughts greatly appreciated.  I believe c# should be building a pointer to the string to be returned but the string over in Python is never changed and I cannot seem to use the Visual Studio debugger probably because the c# code is being called from Python.

```
import threading
import time
from ctypes import*
mydll = cdll.LoadLibrary("C:\\Users\\matthah1\\1data\\Projects\\Europa\\SimpleGUITestDLLClassLibrary1\\SimpleGUITestDLLClassLibrary1\\bin\\x64\\Debug\\SimpleGUITestDLLClassLibrary1.dll")
global strtest
strtest = 'empty'
def startformth():
    mydll.startform()
    print ('leaving startformth')    

ts=threading.Thread(target=startformth)
ts.daemon = True
ts.start();

def run_MS_GUI():
    global strtest

    strtest2 = "**   "
    testpar=76
    while True: 
        mydll.test(testpar, strtest2)
        print ('after call to test strtest2 in thread:', strtest2)   
        time.sleep(1)



t=threading.Thread(target=run_MS_GUI )
t.daemon = True
t.start()
for i in range(40):
   #print ('looping for test strtest  is:', strtest)
   time.sleep(1)
t.stop()
ts.stop()



    [DllExport("test", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]

    static public int test(int testpar, IntPtr par3)
    {


        testpar = testpar + 1;
        testparfromPythong = testpar;
        string inputStr = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(par3);
        string outputStr = "foo\0";
        byte[] outputBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(outputStr);
        Marshal.Copy(outputBytes, 0, par3, outputBytes.Length);

        return 0;

    }
```